# Start button is disabled in Apriori even after discretizing the values

Tags: weka, apriori

I'm trying to mine associate rules using apriori algorithm using week, but I'm unable to perform as the start button is dissabled.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshots, you have **Apriori** selected as algorithm, which has the following capabilities (copy/pasted from the Weka user interface):

```
Class -- Binary class, Missing class values, No class, Nominal class

Attributes -- Binary attributes, Empty nominal attributes, Missing values, Nominal attributes, Unary attributes
```

However, your screenshot of the attributes shows at least one numeric attribute (**Avg_Utilization_Ratio**).

Apriori cannot handle numeric attributes, which is the reason why the *Start* button is disabled.